# HTML email - TD hover to change back background-color not working

Tags: css, hover, html-email, css-tables

My codepen:
http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/iJBrn

Note this isn't for a regular webpage, I'm building an HTML email, however for modern browsers / email clients it would be nice to have a simple rollover color (no javascript). Not sure why my hover isn't work.

I'm using code found from the other TD hover stackoverflow questions I've found so far.

```
td.blue-button:hover {
        background-color: #267aa6;
}
```

How would you create this?

Comment: How are you going to do this in an email? You can't count on an attached stylesheet to be rendered, and you can't inline pseudo-selectors.

Comment: @j08691 It does not have to be an external style sheet. It could just be a `<style>` block in the same HTML document, which would work fine

Comment: Good luck with that. Emails are notoriously difficult to style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You inline style is taking precedence over the external `td.blue-button:hover`.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XSukP/)

Extract the class

```
td.blue-button {
    background-color: #006497;
}

td.blue-button:hover {
    background-color: #267aa6;
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I was worried that older browsers / email clients won't pick up the style tag in the head, what's your opinion on this? Is there a bgcolor in the td fallback? another 8 mins

Comment: AFAIK, IE6+ support it. Are you talking about pre 2006 era ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rktiD).

**HTML:**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="250" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin:0 auto;">
<tr>
    <td class="blue-button" width="250" align="center" style=""><a href="#">reply to request</a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
td.blue-button:hover {
            background-color: #267aa6;
}

td.blue-button {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #014568;
  background-color: #006497; 
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
  border-radius: 4px;
}

td.blue-button a {
  color:#ffffff; 
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #014568;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```